Is there "guilt by association", according to Catholic moral theologians?
In other words, when does association with public sinners become itself a sin or make you a participant in others' sins?
Association is not one of the 9 ways of participating in others' sins:

By counsel
By command
By consent
By provocation
By praise or flattery
By concealment
By partaking
By silence
By defense of the ill done


Would association just mean being friendly with a known sinner? I don't see how that would mean you are participating in their sin.

@jaredad7 By "association" I mean eating with them, living with them, working with them, forming a club or political party with them, or etc.

Jesus ate with sinners.

Is there someone to associate with that is not a sinner?

@MikeBorden Good point. I changed it to "public sinners".

@jaredad7 True, but He didn't join a Freemasonic lodge, Communist political party, or similar association.

You may consider examining the definition of "scandal" and the (mostly historical) category of excommunication vitandi.

You might look at 1 Corinthians chapter 5 where Paul talks about separating from sinners. Not the folks that are in the world but the folks who are in the church and yet who are comfortable  participating in unquestionably sinful behavior.

In my answer I referenced Jewish law and the fact that Jesus associated with sinners. To show why Christians do not make "association" a sin. I see no one else proposing a better answer, look forward to an acceptable answer coming forward.

@Geremia this is why I asked what you meant, and you gave an overly broad definition of association. I worked with a Masonic grand leader or whatever the heck he was, who also claimed to be Greek Orthodox. We had the same employer and were on the same team. I ate lunch with him when he was in town for work events. I don't believe I am guilty of masonry by association with him. I obviously would never recommend that you join a masonic lodge. Joining the lodge would be a sin of itself, not a participation in someone else's sin. Joining would be your own sin.
